# pointer to function to structure, pointer to function to typedef

Tags: function, pointers, typedef

The code in **pointer_to_structure.c** below works ok, but the code in **pointer_to_type-def.c** does not and I don't understand the error.

I'll thank anyone that corrects the code.

**pointer_to_structure.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct sum {
  int a,b,c;
} sum_operation,*ptr;


int main(){

  ptr = &sum_operation;

  (*ptr).a = 1;
  (*ptr).b = 3;

  (*ptr).c =(*ptr).b + (*ptr).a  ;

  printf("%d\n",(*ptr).c);

  return 0;
}
```

**pointer_to_type-def.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct sum {
  int a,b,c;
}sum_operation,*ptr;


int main(){

  ptr = &sum_operation;   //this should be changed

  (*ptr).a = 1;
  (*ptr).b = 3;

  (*ptr).c =(*ptr).b + (*ptr).a  ;

  printf("%d\n",(*ptr).c);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct sum {
int a,b,c;
} mytype;


int main(){

mytype  sum_operation;
mytype *ptr;

ptr = &sum_operation;   //this should be changed

(*ptr).a = 1;
(*ptr).b = 3;

(*ptr).c =(*ptr).b + (*ptr).a  ;

printf("%d\n",(*ptr).c);

return 0;
}
```

Hint: When you use typedef, It creates a type alias for that structure. Hence sum_operation is a type of struct in your code. In the fixed code, alias "mystruct" is given to the struct using typedef and the objects are created using that alias type which are then operated upon normally.

Also, your comment is incorrect. There is no way that code will work if one were to only change that single statement.

Comment: accept the answer if it works by clicking on the tick arrow on the left.

Comment: do you have email? how can i contact you?

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
typedef struct sum {
int a,b,c;
}sum_operation,*ptr;
```

It is equivalent to declaring

```
struct sum {
    int a,b,c;
};

typedef struct sum sum_operation;
```

Therefore `sum_operation` becomes a `typedef` now. So you cannot use a pointer to get the address of `sum_operation` since it is just a type. You need to use

```
sum_operation another;
sum_operation *ptr;
```

And then you can do

```
ptr = &another;
```